# Can I use env.js file instead of .env file to load environment variables using next.js in next.config.js file?

Tags: next.js

Can I use env.js file instead of .env file to load environment variables using next.js in next.config.js file ? If yes, can someone help with syntax with example code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an `env.js` file in your root folder that looks like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  MY_VARIABLE: 'value',
  ANOTHER_VARIABLE: 'blah',
}
```

You can load them in `next.config.js` like this:

```js
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  webpack(config, options) {
    const envObj = require(path.join(__dirname, 'env.js'))

    const env = Object.keys(envObj).reduce((acc, name) => {
      acc[`process.env.${name}`] = JSON.stringify(envObj[name])
      return acc
    }, {})

    config.plugins.push(new webpack.DefinePlugin(env))

    return config
  },
}
```

Then in your app, you can access them as you would access environment variables in node (e.g. `process.env.MY_VARIABLE`). This works on the client side and the server side.

Comment: @sheik FYI, just did a test of this on a project of mine and it worked.